# A tribond with no hints

Tags: visual, tribond

In a non-cryptic way, I don't know the answer to this - I can't figure it out. <s>I'm pretty sure it's a rebus</s> It's a tribond, so I thought you all were my best hope.

[image]

It's not the greatest resolution, but that apple is a red delicious.

Best guess I've come up with is "Mickey Mouse" - but that's weak at best.

Comment: What's the third object?

Comment: Three catnip mice

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think that it is a rebus. It is more like a tribond.

> And something that is common in Apple, key (on a wooden *board*) and mouse is **Computer.** Something that gives strength to my answer is that the key is attached to the board, which makes it to mean keyboard.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of a tribond puzzle.

Comment: we don't have much [tribond puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tribond). These kinds of puzzles ask about the common thing between three things.

Comment: Yep, you were correct when I asked the creator. Thanks!